# Image is not being uplaod in public folder using fs library in nextjs (On Server)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

```
const folderPath = path.join('public', 'images');
if (!fs.existsSync(folderPath)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(folderPath, { recursive: true });
}
const imageDataArray = req.body.split(",");
const fileExtension = imageDataArray[0].split("/")[1].split(";")[0];
const base64Data = imageDataArray[1];
if (["png", "jpg", "jpeg"].includes(fileExtension)) {
    const bufferData = Buffer.from(base64Data, 'base64');
    if (bufferData.length < +process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAX_IMAGE_SIZE_IN_MB * 1024 * 1024) {
        const fileName = Image_${Date.now()}_${Math.random().toString(36).slice(2,11)}.${fileExtension};
        try {
            const filePath = path.join(folderPath, fileName);
            fs.writeFileSync(filePath, bufferData, 'base64');
            res.status(200).json({ fileName: fileName })
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ error: err.message })
        }
    } else {
        res.status(200).json({ error: "File Exceeded Limit" })
    }
} else {
   res.status(200).json({ error: "File Not Allowed" })
}
```

I am not able to upload image on public folder on server while i have every access and enough storage, It's also not working if i build locally and run that build only works while developing. Please help me with it.